# What does $'text' do exactly in Bash? Can it be used in Zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, tr

I recently [run](https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-py/issues/94) into the following proposed solution:

```
cat results.csv | tr $'\x01' \\t > result.csv
```

to convert a malformed csv file (one that uses `\x01` unicode as a separator) into a correct one.

What exactly does $'\x01' tell bash to do? The command does not seem to work well in Zsh.

In case it matters, the actual goal is to convert something like:

> b'flight_uid\twinning_price\tbid_price\timpressions_source_timestamp\n'b'0FY6ZsrnMy\x012000\x012270.0\x011427243278000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01710\x01747.0\x011427243733000\n0FY6ZsrnMy\x012000\x012270.0\x011427245266000\n0FY6ZsrnMy\x012000\x012270.0\x011427245088000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01330\x01747.0\x011427243407000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01710\x01747.0\x011427243981000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01490\x01747.0\x011427245289000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01735\x01747.0\x011427244634000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01420\x01747.0\x011427245595000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01470\x01747.0\x011427242443000\n0FK9yvBt9B\x011050\x011295.0\x011427242253000\n0FK9yvBt9B\x011050\x0112%

into a a regular tab-separated csv file.

When I try this with Zsh, I get the following, which doesn't seem to change anything:

> b'flight_uid\twinning_price\tbid_price\timpressions_source_timestamp\n'b'0FY6ZsrnMy\x012000\x012270.0\x011427243278000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01710\x01747.0\x011427243733000\n0FY6ZsrnMy\x012000\x012270.0\x011427245266000\n0FY6ZsrnMy\x012000\x012270.0\x011427245088000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01330\x01747.0\x011427243407000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01710\x01747.0\x011427243981000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01490\x01747.0\x011427245289000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01735\x01747.0\x011427244634000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01420\x01747.0\x011427245595000\n0FamrXG9AW\x01470\x01747.0\x011427242443000\n0FK9yvBt9B\x011050\x011295.0\x011427242253000\n0FK9yvBt9B\x011050\x0112%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bash documentation:

```
Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by  the
ANSI  C  standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded
as follows:
       \a     alert (bell)
(...)
       \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is  the  octal  value
              nnn (one to three digits)
       \xHH   the  eight-bit  character  whose value is the hexadecimal
              value HH (one or two hex digits)
```

So, in the example you posted, `$'\x01'` is just the character with
code 1, as per your description. From my (very limited) testing, this
appears to be supported by zsh as well:

```
$ printf %s $'\x01' | od -t x1
0000000 01
0000001
```

However, the `tr` command that you posted will only solve your problem
if we assume that your file in fact contains the literal character
with code 1; it appears from the comments that what you have instead
is the four-character string `\x01` where the tab character should
be. The following filter should fix this condition:

```
sed 's/\\x01/\t/g'
```

Comment: Thanks @dhag, I have updated my OP. The command does not seem to change the data in Zsh.

Comment: From the snippet you posted, it looks like you have the literal four-character string `\x01` in your file. Is that what's going on (perhaps run the beginning of your file through `od -c` to make sure)? If so, `sed` may be able to do the job, instead of `tr` (`sed 's/\\x01/\t/g'`).

Comment: Thanks @dhag . You are right, that last command did it. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I updated my answer in consequence. I don't understand, from the code you linked to in your question, how you ended up with `\x01` instead of literal characters with code 1... Something fishy has happened somewhere.